# SAS stored processes in HTML

Tags: sas

How is HTML able to understand the output and run SAS stored processes ?

I understand that if you have "SAS integration technologies" there is a module within that software which uses java to instruct the HTML to talk to your stored process server, is this true ?

Apparently this code would work and run the stored process as requested by the user.

```
   <!-- Welcome page for MyWebApp -->
   <HTML>
   <HEAD><TITLE>Welcome to MyWebApp
      </TITLE></HEAD>
   <BODY><H1>Welcome to MyWebApp</H1>
   <FORM ACTION="/SASStoredProcess/do">
   Please enter your first name:
   <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="FNAME"><BR>
   <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="_program" 
      VALUE="/WebApps/MyWebApp/Ask Color">
   <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Run Program">
   </FORM>
   </BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 5):

You would need to have a metadataserver and a Stored Process webapplication. If these are present in your environment, you need to create a stored process (STP) in metadata. This can be done with SAS Management Console or Enterprise Guide. Using Management Console, right click on the metadatafolder where you want the STP to be stored and select New>Stored Process.
In the New STP wizard, make these choices:

```
Application Server: SASApp
Server type: Stored process server only
Source code location and execution: Allow execution on selected application server only.
Store source code on application server
Source code repository: Select the physical folder where your SAS program is located
Source file: The name of the SAS program (AskColor.sas)
Result capabilities: Stream
```

Now, in your HTML file, in order for the STP to get executed, you could change the value of the _PROGRAM parameter to the path and name in metadata, e.g.:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_program" value="/Shared Data/AskColor">
```

I will often generate the HTML form with the STP itself, so in the program you could do this:

```
data _null_;
  file _webout;
  put "<HTML><FORM action=""&_url."" method=""GET"">";
  put "<input type=""hidden"" name=""_PROGRAM"" id=""_PROGRAM"" value=""&_program"">";
```

All the parameters in the HTML form will be available as macro variables when the SAS program is executed. Now, you need the URL of the STP web application. It could be something like this: http://webserver:8080/SASStoredProcess/do

Tip: Add the parameter _debug=131 to the URL in order to see the parameters and the SAS log.
Good luck!

Comment: also _debug=log can be easier to remember.  Good luck - SAS is very powerful when used to build applications in this fashion!

Comment: @RawFocus - You are right in both comments. If you need an absolute URL, you can build it as you do. But, often a relative URL is enough. _DEBUG=log will not display FIELDS and TIME, you would need to specify _DEBUG=LOG,FIELDS,TIME to get the same info as 131. I think this is inherited from SAS/IntrNet, see https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/dispatch/59547/HTML/default/viewer.htm#debuginp.htm#list

Comment: you can also create a SAS 9 Stored Process (web ready) with this macro:  https://core.sasjs.io/mm__createwebservice_8sas.html